# Avoid using setTimeout() in Elasticsearch requests with Mocha testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, asynchronous

I'm writing unit tests for an API using the Mocha framework, my API uses elasticsearch.

In this case, I'm writing a post test and deleting it afterwards (in `after`).

The problem here is that, when `delete` runs, the values aren't present in the database yet. If I wrap the delete request inside `setTimeout()`, as shown below, it works fine.

How can I avoid using `setTimeout()` in this case?

```
describe('POST New Group', function() {
    this.timeout(MOCHA_TIMEOUT)
    const optionsPost = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'uri': `http://localhost/groups`,
        'json': true,
        'body': {
            "name": "Test",
            "desc": "Lorem ipsum dolore",
            "games": []
        }
    }
    const optionsDelete = {
        'method': 'DELETE',
        'uri': `http://localhost/groups/Test`,
        'json': true
    }

    after(function() {
        console.log("Started delete")

        setTimeout(() => {
            request.delete(optionsDelete, (err, res, body) => {
                console.log("Finished delete")
                assert.equal(res.statusCode, 200)
            })
        }, 1000)


    })

    it('Should return success message with the status code \'201 Created\'', function(done) {
        console.log("Started post")
        request.post(optionsPost, (err, res, body) => {
            console.log("Finished post")
            assert.equal(body.status, 'Group created')
            assert.equal(res.statusCode, 201)
            done()
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. If someone stumbles upon this problem, you have to use ElasticSearch's `Refresh API`.

In this particular case, I can't do a `post` and then a `delete`. I have to do a `post`, a `refresh` and finally a `delete`.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html

Answer (score 1):

better option will be to set `{"refresh": true}` while indexing. this tells elasticsearch to refresh it while indexing and make the data available. So in your case you wouldnt require an extra refrersh api call in between post and delete

Comment: You could have said that almost a month ago, that's brilliant but unfortunately won't help me now :(